# Certificate verification fails for self-signed certificate

Tags: tls, certificates, self-signed

I'm trying to use a service that uses a self-signed cert.

1. Download the cert:

   ```
   # printf QUIT | openssl s_client -connect my-server.net:443 -showcerts 2>/dev/null >  my-server.net.crt
   ```
2. Check that it's self signed (issuer and subject are the same):

   ```
   # openssl x509 -subject -issuer -noout -in my-server.net.crt
   subject=O = Acme Co, CN = Controller Fake Certificate
   issuer=O = Acme Co, CN = Controller Fake Certificate
   ```
3. Try to use it with curl's `--cacert` option:

   ```
   # curl https://my-server.net  --cacert my-server.net.crt
   curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
   More details here: https://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

   curl failed to verify the legitimacy of the server and therefore could not
   establish a secure connection to it. To learn more about this situation and
   how to fix it, please visit the web page mentioned above.
   ```

I don't understand why curl cannot verify the cert.

Comment: For diagnostics, connecting to your server with your browser will probably give more detailed info about the certificate error than curl does.

Comment: Is this really a CA certificate, i.e. has it basic constrains CA true? Otherwise it will be ignored by  `--cacert`.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich you're right it has: `CA:FALSE`

Comment: @SteffenUllrich if you add this as an answer, I'll mark it as the accepted answer.

Comment: In general `s_client -showcerts >file` gets the entire _chain_ sent by the server, but `x509 -in file` displays only the first one while `curl --cacert file` or `s_client -CAfile file` would use _all_ of them. However when the leaf cert is selfsigned as here, the server _shouldn't_ be sending any (additional) chain certs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the comments:

> Is this really a CA certificate, i.e. has it basic constrains CA true? ... – Steffen Ullrich
>   @SteffenUllrich you're right it has: CA:FALSE – little-dude

Signing a certificate requires that the issuer certificate must have the correct flags so that signing is actually allowed. To correctly sign a certificate the issuer certificate need to have the basic constraints CA set to true. This is true both when signing another certificate as for signing the same certificate (i.e. self-signed). It looks like the certificate had not the correct CA:true flag in the case here.

Moreover, the `--cacert` option is like its name says only for CA certificates and not for arbitrary certificates. For example if you have the leaf-certificates of a site  you cannot just add is as trusted with `--cacert` since it is (usually) not a CA certificate. It will simply be ignored when reading the certificates from the given file.

Answer (score 1):

Two guesses:

## 1. Is it allowed to do Server authentication?

Check the Extended / Enhanced Key Usage field of your self-signed cert.

[image: Enhanced Key Usage field of a certificate showing Server Authentication]

## 2. Does the server's hostname appear in the CN or SAN fields?

Curl is going to check that the certificate returned by the server matches the hostname you requested (`my-server.net`).

Comment: So for the certificate key usages, Firefox  lists `Not Critical, Signing, Encipherment`, and extended key usages: `Not Critical, TLS Web Server Authentication`. The Alt Names are listed correctly. So I guess that is all good. The reason it's not working with curl is probably because it has `CA:FALSE` as noted by @SteffenUllrich, then?

Comment: @little-dude Cool. Out of curiosity, how on earth did you manage to generate a self-signed certificate that's not a CA? That is, by definition, an invalid certificate. Does OpenSSL even let you do that?

Comment: I did not generate it myself, I don't manage that server. I'm going to ask the question and report back :)

Comment: Actually, from the CN (`Kubernetes Ingress Controller Fake Certificate` which I shortened a bit in my OP), it looks like the cert if generated by some kubernetes component: https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/issues/1984

Comment: @little-dude Hmm. Maybe self-signed certs are allowed to have `CA:False` -- ie they can sign themself, but not any other certs. I'll have to look that up when I'm at a computer.

Comment: I still don't know why `ingress-nginx` controller generates these weird certificates, but I know _why_ it served it to me. The server implements [SNI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication) and if I don't specify `-servername` with openssl, it served me this default cert instead of the "real" one.